# Azure not seeing my awverify CNAME

Tags: azure, dns, cname

Azure is not seeing the CNAME pointing to awverify.mysite.azurewebsites.net.

I'm wondering if because I added the A record at the same time as the awverify CNAME Azure is having problems seeing the CNAME.

Here were my setup steps:

1. Created A record pointing to Azure's provided IP
2. Created CNAME with awverify.mysite.com to awverify.mysite.azurewebsites.net
3. Tried to add custom domain in Azure's domain manager
4. failed ಠ_ಠ

Azure would could not find the CNAME for awverify.mysite.com after 24 hours of trying.

One thing that was funky was when using the site http://viewdns.info/dnsrecord/?domain=mysite.com it never showed the CNAMEs. Not sure why.

Comment: `mystime.com` != `mysite.com`.

Comment: Good catch but that's not the real site name. :)

Comment: remember that dns is a distributed database. if your domain's TTL is relatively high, any site which has cached lookups on it from BEFORE when you did your changes, those changes will not become visible until those cached records expire and the dns server performs another lookup.

Comment: Does that affect new CNAME records? I'm starting from a fresh DNS setup pointing to my site. The DNS seems to have propagated the A record but for some reason it seems like those CNAME records aren't showing up. If I use https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/ I can see the CNAMEs specifically.

Comment: some servers may opt to cache "negative" responses, so they don't keep hammering on dns for names which really don't exist, but as far as I know those negative caches are supposed to be pretty short in duration. a few minutes at most.

Comment: I've always seen the records show up pretty quickly so that's causing me to think there's an issue somewhere in my setup. I wish I could post images! Thanks for you help!

Comment: @kahlow did you resolve this?  I'm seeing the same issue.

Comment: Should be awverify.www instead of awverify